# html5/other player supporting maximum phones

Tags: html, jwplayer

Right now we are using HTML5 players for our mobile sites, so we have list of all handsets in our database with supporting video format. So for each request we query database to find what format that phone will play ,example  (Samsung J500 : mp4)

We need to remove this dependency and want the player/browser to detect the format and play, we have  mov,mp4,3gp,asf video formats with us.

What is the best way of doing this , given we only knew about the browser ? Our target is to cover maximum handsets to play best quality video that a handset supports .

Answer (score 0):

If you need to support *old* devices, what you currently do seems like a good idea. However, if the device is old enough that it requires a "special" video format, I doubt it supports HTML5?

Since your question specifically mentions HTML5, you can list multiple sources in your Video element. The browser will go down the list until it finds a source it can play.

```
<video controls>
    <source src="Cat.ogv" type="video/ogv">
    <source src="Cat.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

See [Using HTML5 Audio and Video](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video) and [HTML5 Video Fallback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video#Fallback_options)